# How to Pass foreground touch to background touch in between layout

Tags: android, layout, background, foreground, ontouch

I have a requirement where i am having in foreground there is LinearLayout and in background relativelayout is there, foreground is for swiping and background is for simple tap/touch but not swipe, and onTouch() is in foreground and on Tapping at foreground user should be able to go background relativelayout.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I have a customized list-view where left and right two views are there in each row item. To implement swipe delete i have added one more transparent layout say linear layout on top of this item which is having one text-view say Delete button. So i want once swipe the top layout should handle the touch and shows the Delete which is working good but once simple touch happens it should be handled the parent onTouch or on-Click to open the other view which was there in parent layout as above mentioned.

Comment: I did not understand completely. But you can use SimpleGestureListener to detect a single tap using onSingleTapConfirmed function. And in that function you can call the onTouch event of the layout which was intended to get the touch. Does this help?